# centroid of a face of a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

suppose we have a tetrahedron ABCD. The point $D$ is opposite to the face $ABC$. Let $N$ be the centroid of $ABC$ (That is, the point where the medians intersect). Can we write $\vec{DN} = \frac{1}{3}( \vec{AB} + \vec{BC} + \vec{CD} ) $?

Comment: Isn't $\overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{BC} + \overrightarrow{CD} = \overrightarrow{AD}$? Then the equation looks like it is not true in general. Did you mean to write something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\vec{DN} = \frac{1}{3}\left( \vec{DA} + \vec{DB} + \vec{DC} \right)$$